# _begintheadex function call problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, class, visual-studio-express

I have a class SoundManager which contains a function called 'recordLoop'. In the constructor of the SoundManager, I am using this code:

```
    recordHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL,0,recordLoop,
        (void*)exinfo->length,CREATE_SUSPENDED,0);
```

It is giving me the following errors:

```
   error C3867: 'SoundManager::recordLoop': function call missing argument list; use '&SoundManager::recordLoop' to create a pointer to member
   IntelliSense: argument of type "unsigned int (__stdcall SoundManager::*)(void *params)" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)"
```

So I've tried using the &SoundManager::recordLoop as suggested, but it gives me this:

```
   error C2664: '_beginthreadex' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'unsigned int (__stdcall SoundManager::* )(void *)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'
   IntelliSense: argument of type "unsigned int (__stdcall SoundManager::*)(void *params)" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)"
```

Is it illegal to start a thread on a class method or did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Sorry forgot to add the recordLoop >.<  here it is:

```
 public:
 unsigned __stdcall recordLoop(void* params);
```

Comment: Is the recordloop function a static and does it take void* as the argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's illegal to start a thread on a **non-static** class member since there is no way for the created thread to know what `this` is.

What is the definition of `recordLoop`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with casting.
Ignoring all other problems like one mentioned in the answer above, function pointer must be cast to `(unsigned(__stdcall*)(void*))` in _beginthreadex, no matter what type the function is or what is its parameter list.